# Equivalent Java javax.crypto libraries in Objective-C?

Tags: java, objective-c, encryption

I'm doing the following in Java, which I would like to do the equivalent in Objective-C (minus the Base64 bit, which I already got working):

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(PRIVATE_KEY.getBytes(),"HmacSHA1");
mac.init(secret);
result =  Base64.encodeToString(mac.doFinal(data), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Are there any Objective-C libraries that can help me do the equivalent?

*** UPDATE ***

Just an update - I got the following code running, but the `out` comes out null:

```
NSData *keyData = [PRIVATE_KEY dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *clearTextData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};

CCHmacContext hmacContext;
CCHmacInit(&hmacContext, kCCHmacAlgSHA1, keyData.bytes, keyData.length);
CCHmacUpdate(&hmacContext, clearTextData.bytes, clearTextData.length);
CCHmacFinal(&hmacContext, digest);

NSData *out = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

NSLog(@"encrypted data: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[out bytes]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently worked on another project that did HMAC-SHA1 on iPhone.  Here you go!

The secret key is Base64 encoded in a NSString called secretKey
The string to sign is in the NSString called signString.  If you already have NSData, just use that instead of clearTextData.

The output signature will be in base64Enc, or simply 'out' if you don't want it encoded.

```
NSData *keyData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:secretKey];
NSData *clearTextData = [signStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};

CCHmacContext hmacContext;
CCHmacInit(&hmacContext, kCCHmacAlgSHA1, keyData.bytes, keyData.length);
CCHmacUpdate(&hmacContext, clearTextData.bytes, clearTextData.length);
CCHmacFinal(&hmacContext, digest);

NSData *out = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
NSString *base64Enc = [out base64Encoding];
```

Comment: I'm getting null when it returns the out data, and I did check if secretKey and signStr are valid. I'll update the answer with what I got.

Comment: Did you #import "CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h"?  I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Also put a breakpoint after CCHmacFinal and watch the value of digest.  It should be a uint8_t[20] and the values should be something other than nil.

Comment: You probably also need the NSData+Additions category to get Base64 support in NSData. http://svn.cocoasourcecode.com/MGTwitterEngine/NSData+Base64.m

Comment: Yeah, i figured out the problem. It couldn't convert the encrypted data to NSString because it couldn't be interpreted properly. So, what I did was bsae64 encode the NSData first and then use that as a String, since it uses characters that NSString can actually recognize.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at section [3cc of the manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/index.html#group_Section_3cc). It includes various crypto-related algorithms including SHA1, HMAC and MD5. They're pretty low-level compared to a lot of Objective-C code, but they're pretty straight-forward as long as you know pointers.